# Testing significance of linear discriminants

Tags: r, statistical-significance, discriminant-analysis

I have run a discriminant analysis and would like to test the significance of each resulting discriminant function - i.e., does each discriminant function contribute to the separability of the groups? I can't find a definitive answer on how to do this. Most of the reading I have done has shown examples of testing for significance among the groups using MANOVA with respect to the individual, original values, not to the discriminant functions. My approach is to use the predict() function after running the lda, then using the scores that result in individual anovas. Can someone please indicate whether this is valid?

```
#run manova to test for differences among classes based on original input variables 
#optional
mydata.manova <- manova(var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 ~ CLASS,  data=mydata)
summary(mydata.manova, test="Wilks")


#run lda 
mydata.lda <- lda(CLASS ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 +  var5, data=mydata,na.action="na.omit")

#view coefficients and variance explained
mydata.lda


#test significance of each discriminant function in separating the groups
#first predict back to original data to get discimriminant scores? 
mydata.lda.predict <- predict(mydata.lda,data=mydata)

#join predictions to original dataframe
mydata2 <- cbind(mydata, mydata.lda.predict)

#test significance 
test1 <- aov(mydata2$x.LD1 ~d$CLASS)
summary(test1)

test2 <- aov(mydata2$x.LD2 ~d$CLASS)
summary(test2)

test3 <- aov(mydata2$x.LD3 ~d$CLASS)
summary(test3)

test4 <- aov(mydata2$x.LD4 ~d$CLASS)
summary(test4)
```

When I run the above on my data, all the tests come back significant.